# How can I use nested loop to create the dictionary I want?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops

I want to create a dictionary like :

```
{0: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 
 1: {0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}, 
 2: {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14, 4: 15}, 
 3: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20}}
```

And this is  my code :

```
list=[[1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10],
      [11,12,13,14,15],
      [16,17,18,19,20]]
dic={}
dic2={}
for i in range(len(list)): 
    for x in range(len(list[i])): 
        dic[x] = list[i][x] 
        dic2[i]=dic 
print(dic2)
```

And the result is :

```
{0: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20},
 1: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20}, 
 2: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20}, 
 3: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20}}
```

Where did I make mistake? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be:

```
dic = {
    lst_ind: {i_ind: i for i_ind, i in enumerate(lst)}
    for lst_ind, lst in enumerate(list)
}
```

And by the way I would avoid using names of python builtins such as `list` as variable names as this can cause problems, better use something like `lst` or `list_`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to move the `dic2[i]=dic` outside the second loop

```py
list=[[1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10],
      [11,12,13,14,15],
      [16,17,18,19,20]]

dic2={}
for i in range(len(list)): 
    dic={}  
    for x in range(len(list[i])): 
        dic[x] = list[i][x] 
    dic2[i]=dic 
print(dic2)
```

Comment: I did. But it give me the same result?

Comment: I restart my VScode,and it just be fine.
Seems I got some myterious bug.
Anyway,thank you.

Comment: @Sinbad No problem, also its my bad because i forgot to tell you that you also have to re-initialize the `dic` on every single loop. Anyway your welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
f, s = 4,5
dct = {}
for i in range(f):
    dct[i] = {j : i*s+(j+1) for j in range(s)}
print(dct)


# As one-line
# dct = {i : {j : i*s+(j+1) for j in range(s)} for i in range(f)}
```

---

```
{0: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 1: {0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10},
 2: {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14, 4: 15},
 3: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
list=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
dict2={}
for i in range(len(list)):
    dic={}
    for x in range(len(list[i])):
        dic[x]=list[i][x]
    dic2[i]=dic
print(dic2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use 2 dictionaries, It can be solved using single dictionary itself. Hope this helps.

```
dic = {}
for i in range(len(list)):
    dic[i] = { j: l[i][j] for j in range(len(list[i]))}
print(dic)
```

the outupt for the above code is

```
{0: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 
 1: {0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}, 
 2: {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14, 4: 15}, 
 3: {0: 16, 1: 17, 2: 18, 3: 19, 4: 20}}
```